# Find weak solution to Riemann problem for conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Find the weak solution of the following conservation law
> $$ u_t + (u^2)_x = 0 $$
> with the initial condition
> $$ u(x,0) = \left\lbrace
> \begin{aligned}
> &u_l & &\text{if } x < 0 ,\\
> &u_r & &\text{if } x > 0.
> \end{aligned}\right. $$
> Consider both cases $u_l>u_r$ and $u_l<u_r$. Fin the solution at $x=0$ in each case.

### Attempt

We have  equation: $u_t + 2 u u_x = 0 $ and characteristics are given by $t' = 1 $ and $x' = 2u $ and $u' = 0$ and so $u = const$, $t = s$, $x = 2 u s + r $ so that
$$ x = 2 u(x,0) t + r $$
are characteristicts. so that
$$ x = \begin{cases} 2 u_l t + r, \; \; r < 0 \\ 2 u_r t + r, \; \; r > 0 \end{cases} $$
so thereis a shock formation at $x=0$. Any help in how to continue this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very similar to the Riemann problem of the inviscid Burgers' equation (see e.g. [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/750845/418542), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843118/418542), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067749/418542), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/602613/418542) and related posts). For this type of problem, weak solutions are not unique. Thus, I guess that the problem statement asks for the entropy solution. I will provide a detailed general answer for the case of conservation laws $u_t + f(u)_x = 0$ with Riemann data $u(x<0,0) = u_l$ and $u(x>0,0) = u_r$, where the flux $f$ is smooth and convex (the case of concave fluxes is very similar). If the flux has inflection points, the more general solution is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542).

In the case of convex a flux $f$, there are only two possible types of waves:

- *shock waves.* If the solution is a shock wave with speed $s$,
  $$
  u(x,t) = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
  &u_l & &\text{if } x < s t, \\
  &u_r & &\text{if } st < x,
  \end{aligned}\right.
  $$
  then the speed of shock must satisfy the Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition $s = \frac{f(u_l)-f(u_r)}{u_l-u_r}$. Moreover, to be admissible, the shock wave must satisfy the Lax entropy condition $f'(u_l) > s > f'(u_r)$,
  where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$.
- *rarefaction waves.* They are obtained from the self-similarity Ansatz $u(x,t) = v(\xi)$ with $\xi = x/t$, which leads to the identity $f'(v(\xi)) = \xi$. Since $f'$ is an increasing function, we can invert the previous equation to find $v(\xi) = (f')^{-1}(\xi)$. The final solution reads
  $$
  u(x,t) = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
  &u_l & &\text{if } x \leq f'(u_l) t, \\
  &(f')^{-1}(x/t) & &\text{if } f'(u_l) t \leq x \leq f'(u_r) t, \\
  &u_r & &\text{if } f'(u_r) t \leq x,
  \end{aligned}\right.
  $$
  where $(f')^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of $f'$. One notes that this solution requires $f'(u_l) \leq f'(u_r)$.

---

In the present case, the flux $f: u \mapsto u^2$ is a smooth convex function, so that its derivative $f':u\mapsto 2u$ is increasing. Shock waves are obtained for $u_l \geq u_r$ (cf. Lax entropy condition), and rarefaction waves are obtained for $u_l \leq u_r$. In the first case, the shock speed deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition reads $s = u_l + u_r$. The value of the solution at $x=0$ for positive times is $u_r$ if $s < 0$, and $u_l$ otherwise. In the second case, the reciprocal of the derivative is given by $(f')^{-1} : \xi \mapsto \xi/2$. The value of the solution at $x=0$ for positive times is $u_r$ if $u_r < 0$, $u_l$ if $u_l > 0$, and $0$ otherwise (i.e., if $u_l < 0 < u_r $).