# $u_t+[u(1-u)]_x=0$ with initial conditions - Need help with rarefaction wave portion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I need help solving $$u_t+[u(1-u)]_x=0$$ with initial conditions 
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases}
0.75 & |x|<0.5\\
0 & else
\end{cases}
$$
I am trying to use the method of characteristics but I am having trouble with the rarefaction wave part.

First, we can rewrite the PDE as $$u_t+(1-2u)u_x=0$$
So, we have $$\frac{dx}{dt}=1-2u$$ and we know that characteristics are constant because $$\frac{d u(x(t),t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dl t} = u_t+u_x(1-2u)=0$$

So, we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{d t}=1-2u(x,t)=1-2u(\xi,0)$$ and solving for this gives $$x=(1-2u)t+\xi$$

So, I have that there are characteristics that have slope $1-2u(\xi,0)$ so the slope is 1 for $x\leq-0.5$ and $x\geq -0.5$ and we have slope -2 for $-0.5<x<0.5$.

So, there is a shock at $x=-0.5$. The propagation can be found as 
$$s'=\frac{0(1-0)-0.75(1-0.75)}{0-0.75}=1/4$$ So the characteristic propagates as $$\frac{dx}{dt}=1/4$$ $$x(0)=-0.5$$ and we get $x(t)=-0.5+t/4$.

Then there is a rarefaction fan at $x=0.5$. I think that it starts at $x=-t/2 +0.5$ and ends at $x=t+0.5$. I am having a hard time figuring out what the equation is for the fan though.

So, my solution is 
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
0 & x<-0.5+t/4\\
0.75 & -0.5+t/4\leq x\leq -t/2+0.5\\
rarefaction & -t/2+0.5<x<t+0.5\\
0 & x\geq t+0.5
\end{cases}
$$
I would really appreciate help on how to define the rarefaction fan part. I have tried variations of $\frac{x-0.5}{t}$ and $\frac{t+x-0.5}{t-0.5}$ but they don't seem to work right.

Thank you.

Comment: You've written $u_x + (u(1 - u))_x = 0$; shouldn't there be a $t$-deriviative in there somewhere; otherwise, it's an ODE . . .

Comment: Is it supposed to be $u_t + (1-2u)u_x = 0$?

Comment: @Dylan Sorry about that. You are right. I will edit it.

Comment: @RobertLewis you are definitely correct. There is a t derivative. Sorry about the typo there. I fixed it in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out after working on this since yesterday afternoon almost nonstop. We need that the rarefaction satisfies $0.75$ at $x=-0.5t+0.5$ and we need that it also satisfies $0$ at $x=t+0.5$ since these are the initial densities to the left and right of the fan.

So with a bit of algebra, one can find that the rarefaction wave should behave like $$-0.5\bigg(\frac{x-0.5}{t}-1\bigg)$$
since then,

$$-0.5\bigg(\frac{(-0.5t+0.5)-0.5}{t}-1\bigg)=0.75$$ and 
$$-0.5\bigg(\frac{(t+0.5)-0.5}{t}-1\bigg)=0.$$

I jumped for joy when I got this :D

Comment: Nice work!-----

Comment: The general procedure described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542) gives
$$
u(x,t) = \tfrac12 (1 - \xi) , \qquad \xi = (x-0.5)/t
$$
for $x$ between $0.5 - t/2$ and $0.5 + t$, which is the same result as the one in OP.