# Finding the Exact Solution of Nonlinear Transport Equation

Tags: nonlinear-system, partial-differential-equations

Finding the exact solution of the following Riemann problem.
$$\begin{cases}
u_t+(e^u)_x=0 ,\\
u(x, 0)=\begin{cases}
1, & x<0, \\
0, & x>0.
\end{cases}
\end{cases}$$
I have learned how to solve the advection equation, such as 
$$
\vec{u}_t+A\vec{u}_x=0, 
$$with $\vec{u}(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.([Solving Linear Hyperbolic System](https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0016541/Talks/advection.pdf))

But I'm confusing about how to solving this Riemann problem. Any hints or bibliography will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flux $F:u\mapsto e^u$ of the present conservation law $u_t + F(u)_x =0$ is convex. Therefore, the methodology described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542) applies. Rewrite the conservation law in quasi-linear form $u_t + A(u)u_x =0$ to introduce the characteristic speed $A(u)=e^u$. Here, the base characteristic lines intersect ($A(1) > A(0)$): a shock-wave solution is obtained. Its speed $s$ is given by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition
$$
s = \frac{F(1) - F(0)}{1-0} = e-1\, .
$$
The entropy solution reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&1 &&\text{if}\quad x<st ,\\
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x>st .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Note that for the linear advection equation $u_t + Au_x = 0$, the solution would also be a discontinuity, which speed equals the characteristic speed $s=A$.