# Rarefaction Wave in nonlinear PDE $u_t + (u^{3/2})_x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am dealing with the following PDE:
$$u_t + \big(u^{\frac{3}{2}}\big)_{x} = 0$$
subject to:
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & x\leq 0 \\
      4 & 0\leq x\leq 10 \\
      1 & x > 10 
   \end{cases}$$

The solution at $u(x,1)$ is known to be: 
$$u(x,1) = \begin{cases} 
1 & x < \frac{3}{2}\\
\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)^2 & \frac{3}{2} < x <3\\
4 & 3<x<10 + \frac{7}{3}\\
1 & x > 10 + \frac{7}{3}
\end{cases}$$
I have worked through everything, and understand the solution aside from the rarefaction part. I know that one must use $\frac{x}{t}$ as a characteristic equation, but I cannot understand how they jumped from that to $(\frac{2x}{3})^2$ in the final solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general procedure is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542). In the present case, we have the conservation law $u_t + f(u)_x = 0$ with the flux $f: u\mapsto u^{3/2}$. The corresponding characteristic speed is $f'(u) = \tfrac32 u^{1/2}$. Considering a rarefaction wave starting at $x=0$, we have
$$
u(x,t) = (f')^{-1}(x/t) = \big(\tfrac23 x/t\big)^2
$$
for $\tfrac32 t < x< 3 t$. Setting $t=1$ gives the result.