# PDE $u_y+e^uu_x=0$ solution where initial data is discontinuous

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Given a pde $$u_y+e^uu_x=0$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$ with the initial conditions $$u(x,0)=f(x)=\begin{cases} 2 & x<0 \\ 1 & x>0 \end{cases}$$
> Solve the pde.

My attempt so far, I find the characteristic curves for $(s,0,f(s))$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=1$$
which gives $$y=t$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=0$$ which gives $$u=f(s)$$
and $$\frac{dx}{dt}=e^u \implies $$ $$x=e^{f(s)}t+s$$
So
$$u(x,y)=f(x-e^uy)=\begin{cases} 2 & x< e^2 t \\ 1 & x>et \end{cases}$$

Now I know that to find the time the shock forms I must find $t$ such that $$(e^u,1) \cdot (0,-e^{f(s)}f'(s)-1)=0 \implies $$ which gives $$t=\frac{1}{e^{f(s)} f'(s)}$$

But the problem is that $f(s)$ is constant on each interval so the derivative vanishes, therefore the shock time becones infinite, this is what I don't understand, how can I find the time the shock forms?

Comment: In the wording of your question they are three variables $x,y,t$, but no $t$ in the PDE itself. It is written that $u=u(x,y)$ and that $u(x,0)$ is the initial condition. This isn't correct since $y=0$ is not an initial condition which should be at $t=0$. Would you mind clarify and rewrite correctly the question.

Answer (score 1):

The initial data is discontinuous. Therefore, this is a [Riemann problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542) for the PDE $$
u_y + (e^u)_x = 0
$$
rewritten in conservation form, whose flux function $u\mapsto e^u$ is convex. In the present case, the base characteristics intersect, and the solution is a single shock wave with speed $$
s = \frac{e^2 - e^1}{2 - 1} = e\, (e-1) \approx 4.67
$$
deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. The shock forms immediately, at $y=0^+$.

Comment: But what is the breaking time? How do I find it?

Comment: My question was to find the time $t$ the shock forms, in this cases the time $t=\frac{1}{e^{f(s)}f'(s)}$ is not defined for $f'(s)=0$ so how can I find $t$?

Comment: Should I expect that in any Riemann problem with piecewise constant initial conditions where a shock forms, that the shock forms at $t=0$?

Comment: @lost-mid For Riemann problems, solutions are either shocks (forming at $t=0$) or smooth rarefaction waves (or combinations of those). Hence yes, shock formation cannot happen elsewhere for Riemann problems.