# Admissible solution to Riemann problem with unit jump

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

**Question** Consider the equation
$$u_t + (u^4 /4)_x =0. $$
Find the admissible solution for each of the following initial data:
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad & x<0 \\ 0 & x>0\end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 0 \quad & x<0 \\ 1 & x>0\end{cases} .$$
**Attempt** For the initial data
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad & x<0 \\ 0 & x>0\end{cases}$$
the speed of the shock is
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1/4 -0}{1-0} = \frac{1}{4} $$
therefore the solution is
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad & x<t/4 \\ 0 & x>t/4\end{cases} .$$
How can I find the solution for $u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad & x< 1\\ 1 & x>0\end{cases}$ ? Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: The max entropy solution would require a rarefaction wave

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you. How can I find the rarefaction wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apply the method described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542) to the present initial value problem. For the dropping unit discontinuity given by $u(x<0,0)=1$ and $u(x>0,0)=0$, the admissible solution is a shock wave with Rankine-Hugoniot speed $\frac14$. Hence the solution proposed in OP is correct.
For the positive initial jump
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 0 ,\quad & x<0, \\ 1, & x>0,\end{cases} $$
the admissible solution is a rarefaction wave:
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0 ,\quad & x\leq 0, \\
 \sqrt[3]{x/t}, & 0\leq x\leq t, \\
 1, & x\geq t.\end{cases} $$